# Не отображается картинка через background-image

Tags: html, css

Я написал лендинг пейдж. На компьютере локально отображается полностью всё корректно через Live server в VS Code. Но загрузив код на **GitHub Pages** перестает отображаться фоновое изображение
из секции contacts в файле main.css, которое я задал через:

> background-image: url("../../img/contacts_img/footer-bg.svg");>

Пытаясь решить проблему я пришел к выводу, что вся проблема в некорректном пути этих картинок, ведь на GitHub в адрес картинок идет уже другой путь в отличии пути на компьютере, а именно в адрес добавляется мое имя из репозитория, согласно авторизации на GitHub.

Ссылка на репозиторий >  [1]: https://github.com/Bilostenko/Landing-Cutspace
Прошу дать совет как действовать в таких ситуациях, так как столкнулся впервые с этим.

Answer (score 2):

Вот путь до вашей картинки
https://bilostenko.github.io/Landing-Cutspace/img/contacts_img/footer-bg.svg
В css попробуйте так

```
url("../img/contacts_img/footer-bg.svg")
```

Вот скрин - выделил рамкой розовой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, помог Ваш вариант. Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста Дмитрий